# HTML5 + CSS Shared Access

Tags: css, html, formatting, location

I have a question. I got some HTML5 Template with CSS and customized it with power-shell to get a Reporting dashboard. Everything looks good until I hosted on IIS and tried to access from a client machine. Almost all the formatting goes away and since I am linked with some more HTML pages to the main site they also look weird. I know maybe this is because of the location but i used the example like this

```
<li><a href="reports/dbreport.html">Exchange Database</a></li>
```

and it wont either open or if opens looses formatiing.

Please any ideas on how to fix this. Everything works although on the Server where it was built.

Comment: How does your directory tree look like?

Comment: Hi could not understand what u mean. Do you mean this in IIS

Answer (score 0):

You are using relative paths in href attribute. This can by problem if you have different settings on IIS... Same think with src for stylesheets etc...

Comment: Thanks what can be the solution to this then